# How much risk is there for RSA blinding random number not being relatively prime to N

Tags: rsa, blinding

I'm working on the blinding portion of some RSA code.  Some implementations I've looked at don't verify that the random number used for blinding is relative prime to N as described on the Wikipedia page for [blinding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinding_%28cryptography%29):

> RSA blinding involves computing the blinding operation E(x) = (xr)<sup>e</sup>
> mod N, where r is a random integer between 1 and N and relatively
> prime to N (i.e. gcd(r, N) = 1)

I assume this is because finding the blinding factor is expensive (is GDC the fastest/only way?).  That being said, how much of a security risk does the random number used for blinding not being relatively prime to N pose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That being said, how much of a security risk does the random number used for blinding not being relatively prime to N pose?

None, for two reasons:

- The probability of it happening is absurdly tiny; of the $n=pq$ numbers in the range $[0, n)$, there are $p+q-1$ values that are not relatively prime to $n$.  Hence, if you select a value from the range randomly, the probability of it being between relatively prime is $(p+q-1)/pq < 2/q$ (where $q$ is the smaller factor).  If $q$ is a 1024 bit number (which is should be if you're doing RSA-2048), well, anything that happens with probability $2^{-1023}$ can be safely assumed not to happen - you'd have better odds at winning the lottery 30 times in a row.
- If, by some miracle, that does happen, it's not a security issue - you just won't be able to unblind.  The unblind step involves the computation of $r^{-1} \bmod n$; if $r$ is not relatively prime to $n$, that'll fail.  If we look at things more closely, we find that it's not an issue with the unblind algorithm, but with the problem itself - what happens is that, in this case, the $xr$ computation will lose information about $x$ - for example, if $\gcd(r, n) = p$, then $xr$ will contain no information about $x \bmod p$ - because of that, you won't be able to restore that information in the unblind step.

Comment: I agree with the first point, but if it did occur and the anomaly was clear to everyone, then adversaries would be able to factor $n$ by taking a GCD of $N$ with the $E(x)$.

Comment: Even not being able to unblind is a big problem in my mind, even if it turned out not to be a security problem.  Seems like confirming `r` is relative prime to `n` is the safest way to go, even if it is expensive.

Comment: If that is your concern, aren't you also concerned with far more likely events that may also prevent you from unblinding; say, a meteor just happens to strike your computer at the right time...

Comment: @DanielS: if an adversary wants to factor $n$, there are easier ways than collecting $E(x)$ and computing $\gcd( n, E(x))$ - he can pick random values $r$ and compute $\gcd(n, r)$ - exactly the same success probability, and he doesn't have to wait for $E(x)$.  Or, better yet, he can use a real factorization method...

Comment: @poncho, haha, my keen senses are picking up some sarcasm.  My project is on a low power microcontroller, so I was worried that the GDC calculation would be too expensive, but it actually doesn't take too long (less than a second).  And while I am afraid of random meteors, I'm more afraid of someone saying my code is sub-par and doesn't cover corner cases.  Speaking of corner cases, the Wikipedia page I linked to doesn't specify inclusivity.  I.e. which of the following should be my random number criteria? `1 < r < n` or `1 <= r <=n`

Comment: @ubiquibacon: it doesn't really matter, but if you want to be precise, I'd use $1 \le r < n$; that skips the value 0, however you don't want to use that value anyways (and 1 is not a security risk).  Also, you don't really need the GCD - if you try to compute $r^{-1} \bmod n$, and it fails, then you know $r$ and $n$ are not relatively prime - and you need to compute that anyways.  All you need to do is compute that before you publish the blinded value.